# Problem creating path alias in code

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I am creating a node and a path alias roughly as follows:

```
<?php
$node = (object) array( 'type' => 'article');
node_object_prepare($node);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
// ... some more fields get set here...
$node_wrapper->title->set( 'Foo' );
$node_wrapper->save();

// Set the path
$path = array(
  'source' => "node/$node->nid",
  'alias' => "foo/bar",
);
path_save($path);
```

The node is created OK, and the path seems to be created OK, too. I can type `foo/bar` in as the path and I see the new blank page. **However** when I edit that page, the Path Alias is blank?!

I have pathauto installed - could this be something to do with it? Nb. when I edit the page the "Generate path automatically" pathauto checkbox is *not* checked (which is what I'd expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the differences in the `node` table, I noticed that the node created by my code had an empty `language` field. Updating this to `"und"` fixed the node alias.

This makes sense, because [path_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/path_save/7) defaults to `LANGUAGE_NONE` (i.e. `"und"`).

I had assumed that node_prepare would do likewise, but it does not.

So the solution is to set `$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;` at the point of creation.

Also, this is an easier way to create the alias...

```
$node->path = array('alias' => $path, 'pathauto' => FALSE);
```

Comment: Using `$node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'article'));` should take care of the language thing.  Off the top of my head I can't remember if it also takes care of the `node_object_prepare()`.

Comment: Ours is a multilingual site so certainly have to select English for it and still seeing this issue